# How to uninstall java from command line independent of version currently installed in machine?

Tags: cmd

hi i have to write a command line to uninstall java where it get current version already installed in system ?(suppose one system having jre-6u29 where other having jre-7).But i want single command line to uninstall existing version.please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***I have not tested this.***

***Use with EXTREME caution. It WILL NOT prompt for confirmation, and it WILL NOT let you cancel your action***

Open a command prompt using administrator rights, and type in:

```
wmic product where "name like 'Java%'" call uninstall
```

What this simple command is doing is:

- Find all the products installed on your computer which name starts with "Java"
- Uninstalls them without asking for confirmation, nor showing any kind of user interface

Comment: To check the list of products that will be affected, the following command can be used:

`wmic product where "Name like 'Java%'" get Name, Version`

Answer (score 1):

In order to make sure that you get any installation of Java replace 'Java%' with '%Java%' (obviously). So the command would be:

```
wmic product where "name like '%Java%'" call uninstall
```